# what is the image that is placed when I put a link in the status?

Tags: facebook

I have a website and want to put a link to it on my status on facebook.
However, no image is displayed.

How can I determine to display an image with that link?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Indeed. This is the answer. I must point out that I did everything ok, the problem was that I havent fetched the link, and thus the facebook was not updated which thumbnail to present. So the most important stage to do it to fetch the link 
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug